# Changing the size of title of the chapter with the chapter header and vice versa

Tags: chapters, size

I would like to change the size of the chapter title (i.e. blablabla) with the chapter header (Chapter 1) and vice versa.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\chapter{blablabla}
\section{hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The size?  Or, rather, to swap the position of the two?

Comment: Yestop swap the size.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Sorry for the working. The first line of the output is `Chapter 1`, the second line of the output is `blablabla`. They have different size, blablabla is bigger than Chpater 1. I would like that their size get reversed, i.e., `Chapter 1` becomes bigger that `blablabla`.

Answer (score 1):

Class `book` uses `\Huge` for the first line with `Chapter xy` and `\huge` for the chapter title. It is used in macro `\@makechapterhead`. The following example changes the size macros.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Size of chapter titles changed from \Huge to \huge
\patchcmd\@makechapterhead{\Huge}{\huge}{}{%
  \errmessage{First patching \noexpand\@makechapterhead failed}%
}
\patchcmd\@makeschapterhead{\Huge}{\huge}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\@makeschapterhead failed}%
}
% Size of first chapter head line of numbered chapters
% changed from \huge to \Huge
\patchcmd\@makechapterhead{\huge}{\Huge}{}{%
  \errmessage{Second patching \noexpand\@makechapterhead failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{blablabla}
\section{hello}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Below I define `\swapHugehuge` and `\revertHugehuge` that swaps out the definitions of `\Huge` and `\huge` around a redefined `\chapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

% Store original \huge and \Huge definitions
\let\oldHuge\Huge\let\oldhuge\huge
\let\oldchapter\chapter% Store original \chapter

% Define swapping/reverting mechanism
\newcommand{\swapHugehuge}{\let\huge\oldHuge\let\Huge\oldhuge}
\newcommand{\revertHugehuge}{\let\huge\oldhuge\let\Huge\oldHuge}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
  \swapHugehuge
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldchapter*{#3}}% \chapter*{..}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}% \chapter[.]{..}
       {\oldchapter{#3}}% \chapter{..}
    }%
  \revertHugehuge
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\end{document}
```